# Portable font viewer for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, portable, font-utility

I just need some piece of software to quickly open a font file and check what's inside. Requirements:

1. Ability to open a font file.
2. Having a standalone portable version (usually, it's just a .zip archive instead of setup.exe installer) which will never need administrative rights to run. It also means that .NET/Java applications are not acceptable.
3. Open-source/free.

**EDIT**
I forgot to clarify a few things.

Firstly, I need to define what I mean by "font viewer". It is not the application that shows me a portion of text typed in the selected font, it is the application with the interface similar to [BabelMap](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html).
The reason of my dissatisfaction with BabelMap is that it's not a **font viewer**, it's a character map which shows me the entire Unicode grid, but... what should I do with such a grid? Suppose I open a font that contains only 100 glyphs. What will I see? A giant Unicode grid with many thousands of empty cells and a small amount of cells showing how its corresponding char looks in the font??? This type of interface seems totally useless for me. I expect to see a grid with **all glyphs** contained in the font, but without glyphs not supported by the font, and without empty (unused) cells.

Secondly, I need to note that the application should not be limited to **installed** fonts (that is, located in "Windows/Fonts" directory)! I need to open a font file which may be located in **any** directory, without having to "install" the font. The application should provide something like a standard "File > Open" dialogue box, and allow me to select any font file.

Answer (score 1):

[NexusFont](http://www.xiles.net/) has a portable version available for Windows.  It was written by [JungHoon Noh](https://about.me/xiles).  It allows you to view and compare font files.  It is completely free.

I have used it extensively, and I can recommend it.

Here is a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]
*Source: xiles.net*

Comment: Thank you, but this application does not comply with my requirements. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I've used two **Font Viewers** that are portable, open source, gratis, will show fonts in other folders, and will display all characters in the font package but **not** in a grid. You can download and try them, if you wish.

#### 1 - my preferred viewer - http://us.fontviewer.de/Download/

#### 2 - http://www.ampsoft.net/utilities/FontViewer.php

***Hope these will help!***

Comment: It looks like dp4 (fontviewer.de) will meet the querent's needs.